# License.txt files of ASP.NET Core 3.0 projects

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have created a new MVC web application using ASP.NET Core 3.0. I have completed the application and now I want to share it with others in complete source code form.

There are three JS files in the wwwroot folder - jquery, jquery-validate, and jquery-validate-unobtrusive

I have two questions:

1. Is it necessary to distribute LICENSE.TXT file of these three libraries?
2. The jquery-validate-unobtrusive file says :

   Copyright (c) .NET Foundation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. See License.txt in the project root for license information.

So, do I need to place License.txt in my ASP.NET Core MVC project's root or somewhere else? Is it really needed at all?

I would be grateful if somebody can clarify my confusion.

Thank you.

Comment: [Well, what does the Apache licence say?](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0#redistribution)